# VBA: Faster Recordset connection

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following code to access a recordset from SQL Server 2008.

```
Dim cnn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strSQL As String

Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  'ADO Connection
cnn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=" & dbServer & ";" & _
                            "Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=" & dbDatabase
cnn.Open

strSQL = "Select * from mytable"

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

On `rs.Open` it takes from one second to three seconds. Is there a faster way to access the recordset?

The variables dbServer and dbDatabase are defined in a module as a constant string.

Comment: Try making the connection before opening the recordset - is that what's taking the time, or is it running the query ?

Comment: How can I separate the two commands?

Comment: I guess I didn't read your question fully - you're already opening the connection with **cnn.Open**  In that case it seems to be just the time to query that's the problem, and you should follow up on HansUp's suggestions.  Adding some more detail might also help: eg. how large is the dataset you're pulling back?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `mytable` is a base table rather than a VIEW, the SQL is as trivial as is possible i.e. there is no scope for optimization.

If you are bringing the entire table contents over to do further RBAR ("row by agonizing row" = pejorative) processing in VBA code then consider rewriting your procedural logic as a "set-based" paradigm using more complex SQL e.g. adding a `WHERE` clause would be a good start.

If you do need to bring the entire table contents over and the table is relatively large then it will take a relatively long time. Again, there is no scope in your code for optimization.

You are currently performing a synchronous fetch, meaning execution of your VBA code will wait at the `rs.Open` line until the fetch is complete. The effect for your users will be that the application appears frozen, possibly crashed.

An alternative approach is to use an asynchronous fetch. Relocate your code class module, declare the recordset as `WIthEvents` (needs to be relocated to module level) and specify the `adAsyncFetch` option on the recordset before opening it (you may need to alter your approach slightly to accommodate this). This will cause execution to continue past the `rs.Open` as soon as the request has been sent (so you will need to relocate any code that closes the connection/recordset to a separate sub procedure). You can then use the `FetchProgress` and `FetchComplete` events to give feedback to your end users in the application. For more details, see [this MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262311).

I've never been able to get any meaningful 'percent completed' style progress out of the Access engine/provider. But you can at least show a marquee style progress bar to users to reassure them that data is being fetched. They will be able to still interact with the UI (e.g. click on controls) and be reassured that the application has not crashed.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 operations:

1. open connection
2. open recordset using that connection

Where is the delay?

You could add line for `Debug.Print Now()` immediately before the two open statements, and another after the recordset open.

If opening the connection is the bottleneck, see whether using the native client provider speeds things up.  [www.connectionstrings.com: SQL Server Native Client 10.0 OLE DB Provider](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008#p2)

If opening the recordset is the bottleneck, you have several options.  If you don't actually need a dynamic/editable recordset, use adOpenStatic instead of adOpenKeyset.  You could try CommandTypeEnum adCmdTable to open the table instead of using a SELECT statement which returns everything.  Or with the SELECT statement, include an explicit field list instead of "*" ... because "*" requires an extra trip to the server to figure out which fields it represents.  (Although that's probably not a big bottleneck.)  And you could also try a WHERE clause to select a single record based on a primary key value.